# I cant close this android studio setup window

Tags: android-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXyad.png)

I pressed finish so many times but i was not able to close it.
Can anyone help me understand whats the problem, this happened when i was trying to install the android studio for the first time, and during the process installing HAXM was failed so i tried to abort the ops and tried to close the setup window but its not working.